# Call a REST API from Kusto function

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a logs endpoint rest url that I want to call and get the contents by calling a function. In a simplified way, create function like below.

```
create function getData(url:string)
{
let data = curl GET url;
print data
}

//Call it.
getData("<some rest url here>")
```

The [documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/rest/request) seems to talk about Kusto's own APIs not not how to call an external API. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you reference relates to calling Kusto service REST APIs.
Kusto query language is a query language, not a open-ended programming platform.
Call-outs to external sources such as SQL Azure are possible, but subject to certain restrictions, primarily security-oriented by nature.
See [external data operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/externaldata-operator), [sql_request plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/sqlrequestplugin?pivots=azuredataexplorer), and [callout policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/calloutpolicy) articles.